# Fully Utilise CPU and Memory

Tags: windows, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-usage

I have a system - processor 2.8 ghz, 20 physical cores, 40 logical cores, 128 gb ram and 4tb hard drive.

Scenario:

I am running 3 (independent) python base processes/scripts (running independently) that read data from file and write it to database. They are taking time while not using CPU and Memory 100% not even 40%.

Why is it so? (I think it depends upon OS)

How can I configure it to utilise CPU and Memory more?

I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at processoraffinity and processpriority

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well I want configuration (steps), not the code, to utilise my CPU and Memory 100% (or atleast 80%) physically.

Answer (score 0):

A process (including a python script) isn't going to use any more cores than it has running threads. So if your python script is single-threaded, it's only going to use a single core.

Further, disk and database operations will stall the process while blocked on I/O and network.  (Effective CPU usage == 0).

In other words, your program may not be "cpu bound" if it's doing a lot of I/O.

I'm not sure what your programs do, but if the problem at hand can be parallelized (split up into multiple independent tasks), then it might lend itself to having more threads or processes to take advantage of the extra hardware you have.  But it's tricky and *very hard* to get this right and get the performance gain.